# "Preview" Track Changes in Word 2007/2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I hate using Word's track changes feature, because it is very difficult to determine what the document will look like without accepting changes to the document:

- I don't know how many lines the document will take up
- I don't know if I missed any spacing or word-adjacency problems in my changes

The only way I can verify that the final document looks OK is to **"accept all changes in document" and then close and re-open the file**.

Is there a better way to "preview" the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to click on 'Final' in the Review Tab to view what the document will look like if all changes are accepted (before you accept any changes)

Comment: Thank you! Wow, I must be blind because that was so obvious but I never saw the drop-down box. Perhaps that's why google was no help because it was supposedly so easy nobody would ask about it? Haha